# jQuery slideUp doesn't work within ajax div that has loaded with slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Once a link class is clicked, a div slides down with loaded Ajax content:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
$(".read a").click(function(){
    var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");

    $("#fold-above").slideDown(500);        
    $("#fold-above").load("<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/ajaxpost/",{id:post_id});
    return false;
});
});
```

Within that loaded Ajax content, there is a link which should slide the parent div back up:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".closeUp").click(function (event){   
    $('#fold-above').slideToggle();
});
});
```

What I think is happening might be that there is a nesting issue, maybe with ajax?

Wouldn't the scope of the call to the #fold-above, which contains the div to click on in order to slide it back up, reach back to that point in the hierarchy?

Let me know if more code is needed as example or output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `.closeUp` is loaded via ajax and thus does not exist when the `.click` method is called.  You need to use event delegation instead.

```
$(document).on('click', '.closeUp', function () {
    $('#fold-above').slideToggle();
});
```

Ideally choose a parent that is closer to `.closeUp` than `document`.

Comment: By 'closer' do you mean a div which is closer by levels of hierarchy? Your solution works!